# ag-grid ng build --prod fails : Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: angular, ag-grid

**ng build** fails on **ag-grid gridOptionsWrapper**.  See below.

```
==> ng build --prod
Date: 2018-06-01T10:20:07.564Z                                                            
Hash: e43a7d775a617f72e760
Time: 84869ms
chunk {scripts} scripts.385b291e179030219400.bundle.js (scripts) 137 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {0} main.eb9c978f12021c39965e.bundle.js (main) 2.22 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {1} polyfills.c9bd3d92b786a9531262.bundle.js (polyfills) 166 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {2} styles.e270cced36800690ed11.bundle.css (styles) 307 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {3} inline.318b50c57b4eba3d437b.bundle.js (inline) 796 bytes [entry] [rendered]

ERROR in ./node_modules/ag-grid/dist/lib/gridOptionsWrapper.js
Module build failed: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Object.forEachChild (/home/jhalliley/work/my-ui/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:12719:26)
    at traverse (/home/jhalliley/work/my-ui/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:29674:110)
    at visitNode (/home/jhalliley/work/my-ui/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:12690:24)
    at Object.forEachChild (/home/jhalliley/work/my-ui/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:12821:24)
    at traverse (/home/jhalliley/work/my-ui/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:29674:110)
    at visitNode (/home/jhalliley/work/my-ui/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:12690:24)
    at Object.forEachChild (/home/jhalliley/work/my-ui/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:12915:24)
    at traverse (/home/jhalliley/work/my-ui/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:29674:110)
    at visitNodes (/home/jhalliley/work/my-ui/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:12699:30)
    at Object.forEachChild (/home/jhalliley/work/my-ui/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:12875:24)
    at traverse (/home/jhalliley/work/my-ui/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:29674:110)
    at containsArgumentsReference (/home/jhalliley/work/my-ui/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:29657:56)
    at getSignatureFromDeclaration (/home/jhalliley/work/my-ui/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:29618:84)
    at getSignaturesOfSymbol (/home/jhalliley/work/my-ui/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:29708:37)
    at resolveAnonymousTypeMembers (/home/jhalliley/work/my-ui/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:28899:43)
    at resolveStructuredTypeMembers (/home/jhalliley/work/my-ui/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:29031:25)
```

Any ideas on how to get this build to succeed?  Is this an ag-grid issue, or an ng build issue?  I don't see a way to increase the stack size for ng build.

Comment: `  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^0.4.2",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^0.4.2",
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.6",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.6",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.6",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.6",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^2.0.0",
    "ag-grid": "^17.0.0",
    "ag-grid-angular": "^17.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.7",
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^6.0.7",  `

Comment: Once I updated to the correct version of node, removed node_modules, re-installed all my package dependencies, this build issue went away.

Comment: What is the correct version of node?  I am getting this error intermittently after upgrading to angular 6

Comment: I'm using angular 6, node 8.11.3, and npm 5.6.0, but I'm no longer getting this message.  Instead, I get an error during a prod build with ngClass :(

Comment: Still getting this issue with A6 (6.0.5) and ag-grid 18.1.2

Comment: In the meantime GridOptionsWrapper [has been removed](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/commit/53d6dd2135b898b07c2eb822e22b6ac3676428e6) for v29

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by switching off build optimizer with the production build. It is not the ideal solution. but that works until a proper fix is found for this.

```
ng build --prod --build-optimizer=false
```

**Note**: Switching off optimization could increase your build output size.

Update: I ended up downgrading to 17.1.1 and that solved the issue.